# How can I convert a JSON string to an <Anonymous Type>?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to convert a JSON string (built from a dynamic object to PSON via NewtonSoft back to a dynamic object.

The call:

```
dynamic? dataFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message.Data);
```

gives me `JObject` which, while it is dynamic, is not a true dynamic object. And this is a problem because, to access `dataFromJson.Event.Subject` as a string, I need to call `dataFromJson.Event.Subject.ToString()`.

As I am passing this dynamic object to SendGrid, this won't work. Because SendGrid's template can be told to substitute `{{Event.Subject}}` but it cannot be told to substitute  `{{Event.Subject.ToString()}}`

So how can I convert a JSON string back into a true dynamic `<Anonymous Type>`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "true dynamic type". `dynamic` is just a cover for what the type really is - in your case it's a `JObject` / `JValue`, but it could also be an `ExpandoObject`. You can't make an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-c)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That link does not (previously read it) as it returns `JObject` which requires the explicit `ToString()` calls.

Comment: All 22 Answers?!?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't see any that provided the answer I need. And a search for "expando" has zero hits. So correct, none of the 22 answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types are defined at compile time - so you can't "dynamically" create them the way you want.

There are ways with Newtonsoft.Json and the [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-8.0). Utilizing the [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_ExpandoObjectConverter.htm) might do the trick for you.

Here a small demo:

```cs
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;


const string jsonString = """
                          {
                             "Event":{
                                "Subject":"Meeting",
                                "Location":"Conference Room"
                             }
                          }
                          """;

var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic dataFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString, converter);

Console.WriteLine(dataFromJson.Event.Subject);
Console.WriteLine(dataFromJson.Event.Location);
```

That prints:

```
Meeting
Conference Room
```

EDIT:

Good point from [@gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171) - you can see that the actual type is a string:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(dataFromJson.Event.Subject.GetType());
```

Will print `System.String`.

---

A bit more context about "anonymous types". They are syntactic sugar. So the compiler does generate real classes for you at compile time and substitute your calls with those generated ones.

So this code:

```cs
var link = new { Name = "Link" };

Console.WriteLine(link.Name);
```

Becomes this:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<Name>j__TPar>
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Name>j__TPar <Name>i__Field;

    public <Name>j__TPar Name
    {
        get
        {
            return <Name>i__Field;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <>f__AnonymousType0(<Name>j__TPar Name)
    {
        <Name>i__Field = Name;
    }

    // Way more generated code here ...
}

// This creates the class from above
Console.WriteLine(new <>f__AnonymousType0<string>("Link").Name);
```

If you want to play around, you can use [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwAYCwAoZBGTmBuEATgAQA2sA1iQLwkwCmA7iQN4kByEYDtJARABkq/EgF8A3HizYAnAAoKMSgDouPAJQSgA) and check the lowered code.

Comment: And the more important fact is that the type of `dataFromJson.Event.Subject` is `System.String` as apposed to a `JValue`. Console.WriteLine can hide the fact that is does an implicit `.ToString()`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/l2D9a5

Comment: Perfect Input - I added that to the answer as well, crediting you.